# Restore with Duplicator, URL is concatenated twice

Tags: plugins

I have restored a Wordpress web site using Duplicator plugin.
No warnings or errors in the restore process.

When browsing to the root page, it sort of works (CSS is messed up), but when I try to login from `new-site.com/wp-login.php` , I get the username/password prompt, but the post back redirects me to: `new-site.comnewsite.com/wp-login.php`

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to [update the URLs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) directly form the database

Comment: @denis.stoyanov  thanks, editing the wp-config.php and adding `define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');  
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com'); ` did the trick

Answer (score 1):

Magnus solved the issue by resetting the `wp_home` and `wp_site_url` options via the following code in `wp-config.php`:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Thanks to denis.stoyanov's tip about the [Moving WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) Codex entry.